# 2 Finger swipe-up action in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, appdelegate

I want to change the Navigation Bar Tint Colour when the user swipes up with 2 fingers. I need to do this in the App Delegate so that I can universally change all the nav bar tint colours. I can call a gesture but I'm not sure how to actually get an action called. Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try writing like:

```
[self.navController.view addGestureRecognizer:yourGestureInstanceHere];
```

Here `yourGestureInstanceHere` represents a swipe gesture with number of taps as 2.

Also, I would suggest to sub class your UINavigationController and write this functionality there, instead of AppDelegate. `AppDelegate` is not the class to handle these functionalities.

**EDIT**

```
-(void)addGestureToNavigationController

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];

    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

     swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;

    [swipeRight setDelegate:self];

    [self.navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

}

// Selector

-(void)handleSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer

{

    // TODO : Write change tint colour logic

}
```

Comment: This is a great answer but I need to set the change globally and I'm not sure this solution solves this :/

Comment: Navigation bar appears only in navigation controller, and once you sub class navigation controller with this functionality where ever it is used, this functionality will appears to work globally.